# Jack microphone doesn't work but USB one does

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone, headphone-jack, 3.5mm

I have a Dell Inspiron 2-in-1 laptop with Win10 installed (with all the latest updates). Also, I have 2 headphones, both with microphones - one 3.5 jack Chinese noname one and one USB Logitech overhead one.

When I plug my jack microphone in, it isn't recognized - the sound is played through my laptop speaker. I've tried it at another PC and with my smartphone - it works well, the issue is with the laptop only.

Not Skype nor any other apps doesn't recognize the jack microphone, however USB headphone's microphone works well - it is recognized and works nicely in all the apps.

Comment: After some update the whole jack stopped working: I plugged the headphones in but sound went out of the laptop speakers. In my research on how to fix that I've found that _Realtek High Definition Audio Driver_ app (_"0009-64bit_Win7_Win8_Win81_Win10_R282.exe"_) helps as it asks what has been inserted - and you can choose to stream audio through headphones at that moment instead of speakers.


That app didn't help with the initial issue, though.

Answer (score 0):

Since the sound from the mic plays through the laptop's speaker, obviously, it *is* recognized, but is being *misdirected* to the speaker, rather than Skype. You might try a third-party app, such as [VB-CABLE Virtual Audio Device](https://www.vb-audio.com/Cable/), to send the microphone output to the correct input.

However, look at the Microphone Properties in the Sound Control Panel. It is likely misconfigured, e.g., set up to listen to the device (i.e., "monitor"), or is directed to the wrong playback device.

[image: Microphone Properties]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, @drmoishe-pippik!
I've followed your advice and it didn't help, unfortunately. Here's how it looks it Skype afterwards - no sound is detected from this microphone: https://imgur.com/uQuqCJS.